Find the probability that strictly $2$ people arrived in the first hour in a Poisson Process

Let the number of people arriving at a shop within the time interval $[0,t]$ be $X_t$. $4$ customers arrived in the first $2$ hours. Find the probability that strictly $2$ people arrived in the first hour.

I know the Poisson distribution is (provided $x=0,1,2,...$):
$$f(x|\lambda)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$$ I'm not sure what "$\lambda$" is. Is it simply the expected value? In that case $\lambda=\frac{4}{2}\cdot 1=2$ customers per hour. So $f(2|\lambda = 2)=\frac{e^{-2}\cdot 2^2}{2!}=2e^{-2}$?

The $\lambda$ is the rate of the Poisson distribution, but you wouldn't use the Poisson distribution directly. Rather, you use the fact that the Poisson process has independent arrivals. So each of the four arrivals is equally likely to have occurred at any time in the two-hour interval.

@BrianTung Why doesn't what I did work? I guess $X_2=4$. We want $P(X_1=2)$. I'm not sure how to use the fact about independence

Because you're not conditioning on the fact that there are four arrivals. ¶ The problem is actually simpler than that. You don't know the unconditional rate of arrivals $\lambda$, and you don't need to. Suppose I tell you that some customer arrived in those two hours. What is the probability that it arrived in the first hour? Apply this same reasoning to each of the four customers, bearing in mind that they're independent of each other.

Here $\lambda$ is not known, which on the face of it may seem like you don't have enough information, but in fact you do.
In a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$, the number of arrivals in an interval of length $t$ is distributed $Po(\lambda t)$, and disjoint intervals are independent. What this means for you is that the number of arrivals in the first hour (call this $X$) and the number of arrivals in the second hour (call this $Y$) are independent $Po(\lambda)$ random variables. Also, $X+Y$ is distributed $Po(2\lambda)$.
You are asked for the conditional probability $\Pr(X=2\mid X+Y=4)$. We can calculate this as follows:
$$\Pr(X=2\mid X+Y=4)=\frac{\Pr(X=2)\Pr(Y=2)}{\Pr(X+Y=4)},$$
and if you calculate this correctly, all the $\lambda$s will cancel, meaning that the answer does not depend on $\lambda$.

So $$\frac{f(2|\lambda)^2}{f(4|2\lambda)}=3/8$$?

@Rory-Laughlin yes, that's right. In fact conditional on there being $n$ arrivals in time $t$, the number of them that arrived in the first $pt$ is $Bin(n/p)$ distributed.
